# Convert Android SMS table date to meaningful DateTime format using other than Java

Tags: .net, android, date, sms

I'm wondering how to convert Sms table date value e.g. 1293457709636 (miliseconds) to meaningful Date time value using Microsoft platforms, not Java.

I've just made a backup of my SMS messages from a HTC phone. I exported as XML file and for the date i have something like this: 1301061775000. I've got a solution from this post: [Android - get date time from SMS timestamp in miliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539490) but unfortunately require to have installed and also knowledge of Java which i'm not.

It is possible to convert from this format to something like mm/dd/yyyy HH:ii:ss using Microsoft (don't shoot me!) tools/ide/languages (.NET, C#, VB) or PHP because I have to automate somehow this process since there are more than 600 messages.

Answer (score 1):

The android datetime is milli-secs since Jan 1, 1970. I use the following exention method to convert it to a .NET DateTimeOffset.

```
public static DateTimeOffset Epoch = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1), TimeSpan.Zero);

...

public static DateTimeOffset FromMilliSecsSinceEpoch(this long millSecs)
{
    return Epoch + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millSecs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the clarification! With this in mind I've found this site: http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/batch-convert.php and it does all I need. Thnx again!

Answer (score 0):

Just divide your date by 1000. For example:

```
$androidDate = '1237653891234';

$MyDate = $androidDate/1000;

$NewDate = date('D/M/Y-h:i:s A, $MyDate);
```

will output `DD/MM/YYYY-00:00:00 AM`